# Python for loop which begin from 2 to 10 and then cover 0 and 1

Tags: python, list, loops

I am looking for simple solution for the following problem.

Do we have a *for*-loop for this kind of usage in python?

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1]
```

I have an implementation using a *while*-loop:

```
i = 2
while True:
    i = i%9
    if i == 1:
        break
    # payload code here
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for i in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1):
```

...

```
for i in range(2, 10) + range(2):
```

...

```
for i in itertools.chain(xrange(2, 10), xrange(2)):
```

...

```
for i in (x % 10 for x in xrange(2, 12)):
```

Comment: Wouldn't `for i in ((x + 2) % 10 for x in range(10)):` be more readable?

Comment: @Bengt: It depends on what you want the loop to express.

Comment: @Bengt It's less efficient to perform two arithmetic operations.

Comment: @2rs2ts : In such a small loop, it really doesn't mater if we use two operation or one. both are atomic operations which will be done pretty fast.

Comment: @Emax Certainly. I only said so for posterity's sake.

Comment: We basically want 10 numbers ranging from 0 to 10 in ascending order and start with 2. I do not see a 12 in that sentence.

Comment: @Bengt, maybe you could compromise on `for i in (x % 10 for x in xrange(2, 2+10))`? I find the form in the answer to be quite readable, more so than your variation, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: @MarkRansom These are sure subtle differences. Your compromise would be slightly faster than mine and slower than the original, so they all have their pros and cons. I feel like this needs to be an own function if used frequently in a codebase, because sooner or later one will mix up the numbers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `range`:

```
>>> for i in range(2,10) + range(0,2):
...     print i
...     
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
```

Or using `itertools.chain`(works in both py2 and py3):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> for i in chain(range(2,10),range(0,2)):
    print (i)
...     
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
```

Comment: Nice easy solution, unfortunately it breaks in Python 3. You need to use `list(range(...))`.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's not a good way to do it. `itertools.chain(range(...), range(...))` is the much better way.

Comment: @Lattyware, better perhaps but not as simple. It's a shame that Python 3 lost such an easy way to make a concrete sequence.

Comment: @MarkRansom The reality is that making concrete sequences is something you want to avoid doing - Python 3 makes it much more obvious you are doing something wrong if you go around making lists all the time.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
for i in range(2,10)+[0,1]:  
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in [`range` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) and the [modulo operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print((i + 2) % 10)
... 
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
```

In Python3 you can boil it down to one line using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the [`print` function`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
>>> [print((x + 2) % 10) for x in range(10)] and None
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
```

In Python2 prepend that with:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
```

Or if you only want the list:

```
>>> [(x + 2) % 10 for x in range(10)]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the overhead of the `print` statement/function I changed every occurrence of `print` to `pass`, but here are the `timeit` results for the different approaches, run 10000000 times each:

#### Using itertools.chain:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='for i in chain(xrange(2,10),xrange(0,2)): pass', setup='from itertools import chain', number=10000000)
11.17552900314331     # Ignacio
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='for i in chain(range(2,10),range(0,2)): pass', setup='from itertools import chain', number=10000000)
13.646738052368164    # Ashwini
```

#### Using modulus:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='for i in range(10): (i+2) % 10', number = 10000000)
13.806042909622192    # Bengt
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='for i in (x % 10 for x in xrange(2, 12)): pass', number=10000000)
18.127070903778076    # Ignacio
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='[(x+2)%10 for x in range(10)] and None', number=10000000)
21.191375017166138    # Bengt
```

#### Appending ranges:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='for i in range(2,10) + [0,1]: pass', number=10000000) 
10.056025981903076    # Hardik
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='for i in range(2,10) + range(2): pass', number=10000000)
11.409713983535767    # Ignacio
```

#### Literal expressions:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='for i in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1): pass', number=10000000)
2.8564839363098145    # Ignacio
```

Depressing how the most efficient method is the literal expression of the numbers through which to iterate, but, it involves the least allocation and the least arithmetic.

Comment: Core finding of the day: Hardcoding is fast.